# Create RSS feeds on a set of tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, questions, feed

It seems to me that if I want to help on StackOverflow.com, I might want to monitor new questions using an RSS feed for certain tags only.  That way I could see questions that relate to the subject area where I can best help.

How do I filter questions by tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To subscribe to a single feed for multiple tags, use "or" in the URL. For example, if I wanted to subscribe to the questions tagged `status-completed` or `status-declined` here, I would use the following URL:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/status-completed+or+status-declined
```

You can also use this trick when browsing with tags:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+django
```

(further reading: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/)

Comment: I did not know about this. That looks extremely helpful.

Comment: There's a bug in this answer. The url given gives you `status-completed` **or** `status-declined`

Comment: Will this find questions that are not newly posted, but newly tagged into one of the categories?

Comment: Why is this not working for certain tags like: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/node.js ? While the same is working for normal web requests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js

Answer (score 3):

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/[insert tag name here]
```

Example: If there is a tag called "hotdogs" I can subscribe to that tag feed with the url:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/hotdogs

You can filter questions by tag by adding tags to you interesting tags list (that will provide highlighting for questions that come through matching your interesting tags). By clicking on a tag, you will be displayed a list of questions that match the tag you are looking for.

Another method is to use the search box and search for '[tag name]' (include the square brackets) and that will search specifically for that tag. Searching for '[tag name] my query' will search the questions for you query and limit the results only to those falling within [tag name]