# Is there documentation on how to use Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, documentation

I asked [a Meta SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/is-there-a-way-to-do-rss-feeds-on-a-set-of-tags) about RSS feeds.  Now I am wondering if there is documentation on learning all of the ins and outs of SO.  What are the different URL combinations that I can use?  How do I become a power user?  How can I follow answers to all of my questions?   Can I exclude a string from a search?

Show me the docs, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best resource right now is the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: Thanks...very helpful.  However it does not really cover url construction for searching or doing rss feeds or filtering by topic/url/user.  Is there  a place for all that syntax?

Seth