# RSS feed of your favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, user-accounts, feed

It would be nice if we could subscribe to an RSS feed of all the questions that match your 'favorite' tags i.e. an RSS feed of the questions that get highlighted as yellow when viewing the question list.

You can achieve a similar effect by combining tags as described [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/is-there-a-way-to-do-rss-feeds-on-a-set-of-tags), however this is a pain to maintain, requiring the RSS URL to be edited in the feed reader if you start monitoring new tags, or stop monitoring old tags, also you have to worry about getting the syntax correct (c%23 instead of c# as an example).

It would be much nicer if we could simply subscribe to a URL such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/interesting/41301

Then you could change the tags that are included in that feed from the ‘prefs’ subsection of the user account area.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is a default tag filter on https://stackexchange.com but you must be logged in:

1. Click "**Filtered Questions**" at the top
   [image: stackexchange.com tagged questions, my filters (updated)]

2. Look for the default "**Favorite Tags**" filter.

[image: default Favorite Tags filter]

You can browse it in your browser, or have it emailed to you, or get the RSS feed at the bottom of the page (also present in the headers, too, if your browser auto-detects).

[image: favorite tags RSS feed]

Comment: It is now "Hot Questions" to "My filters". It would be cool to have this per site, too.

Comment: It would be more useful if "ignored tags" overrode favorites and removed them from the feed: ["Favorite Tags" RSS feed should not list things that also have "Ignored Tags"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112774/130885)

Comment: This looks outdated, can anyone please update this? I just don't find a way to get this feed.

Comment: Im with @Raphael. It would be nice to have site per site.

Comment: @jachguate - click Tags, search for your tag, then hover over the tag until the context menu appears and click 'subscribe'... ack

Comment: I clicked on the RSS button and got a whole load of script but no updates. Did I miss something?

Comment: @jeff-atwood — Am I missing something, or is this answer is *way* out-of-date?  The new place to find the ***Favorite Tags* RSS feed** is, while logged in: Go to [this page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags), and scroll to the bottom. That's the current location of the ***Favorite Tags Feed***, correct?  I try to avoid editing answers in general, but feels like either I've gotta be wrong, or else user #1's answers should either be off limits...  (On the other hand, *"Can I, can I ?!"*, it's the closest I've ever been to a celebrity!)

Comment: @QHarr - Did you get it figured out?  Do you have an RSS Reader installed?

Comment: Someone else gave an updated answer pointing to where the button now is.

Comment: @QHarr - According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers), it's best to edit outdated answers instead of creating a new one, especially if they're highly up-voted (and therefore "stuck" at the top of the list).

Comment: @ashleedawg  I have not been brave enough to edit answers yet!

Comment: @QHarr - I've edited a couple, but not to *change* anything, only to *supplement* with links etc, which I was *just about* to post when they posted a similar solution.  As for this one (as I'm not getting any other feedback) could you confirm: Jeff's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101276/370758) no longer works, but mine (in my [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags/101276?noredirect=1#comment999468_101276)) **does** work, correct?

Comment: @QHarr You would right-click the RSS link to get the URL, which you would paste into an RSS News aggregator. There are lots out there, both standalone or browser extensions. I just started using [Simple RSS Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-rss-reader-srr/) for Firefox, which shows new questions in my toolbar.

Comment: @ashleedawg I will try again Monday and see what happens. Many thanks!

Comment: So yah... Firefox will happily deal with RSS feed automatically but Chrome you gotta go download a reader.

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE**

A solution [has been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-interesting-tags/74964#74964), but, since the cross-tag import process is for all of your Stack Exchange favorite tags, you can use [my script](https://bitbucket.org/mrucci/sxsync/src/default/sxsync.sh) to **fetch the updated list of current favorite tags** for specific Stack Exchange instances.

**Usage**

Insert your user name, your user ID's and the Stack Exchange websites you want, e.g.:

```
user=mrucci
sxname=(stackoverflow.com serverfault.com superuser.com)
userID=(133106 25062 16752)
```

then execute it:

```
$ ./sxsync.sh
```

And the output should be something like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/+or+c+or+opengl+or+graphics+or+latex+or+android+or+wmii+or+glut+or+opencv+or+3d+or+3dgraphics+or+beamer+or+wiimote+or+beginner
http://serverfault.com/feeds/tag/+or+linux+or+ubuntu+or+vim+or+rsync+or+gnome
http://superuser.com/feeds/tag/+or+linux+or+ubuntu+or+tiling+or+latex+or+beamer+or+vim+or+gvim+or+vimperator+or+script+or+bash+or+gimp+or+photoshop+or+inkscape+or+programming+or+blender+or+rsync
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but I do not see this as a viable solution - in fact you cannot use in Google Reader or something similar - you will have to re-subscribe each time you add a new tag.

Comment: True, but you don't have to manually recreate the rss feed url or adjust it by manually removing the no-more interesting tags and adding the new interesting tags.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore tags?

Comment: Yes @endolith,  you can simply add `-tag` to the list.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python+-django will give you all question tagged python but not django.

Comment: The script link is dead. Anyone have a copy?

Comment: @Dr-Bracket , I've updated the link, but the script is a little hack from 2012 and and has never been used since.  There's very little chance it still works.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know why it is so hard to add an RSS feed based on tags. I couldn't seem to follow @Jeff's directions and it seemed like too much trouble to run a script. However, taking a clue from @mrucci's answer and doing some more experimenting, I found a way to get the RSS feeds that I want without too much trouble.

The general format is

`[stack exchange site]/feeds/tag/[your tag name](+[and|or]+[second tag name])`

So since I wanted to get a feed for the `android-layout` tag I did

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/android-layout

You can also use the AND and OR operators by including `+and+` and `+or+` between the tag names. For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/android-layout+and+relativelayout

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/android+or+ios+or+java+or+swift

Just enter addresses like these into your feed reader and you are good to go.

**Update**

After rereading the OP's question, I realized that my answer does not solve the question of getting all your current favorite tags with a single link. Sorry to the OP for that. However, the above method is as much as I needed and so I will leave my answer for others who come here with similar requirements.

Comment: This is really great anyway! Nowhere I found the "general" way to get this, only a single tag was usually shown, but I needed more :)

Comment: I found this very helpful and the easiest way to add in a feed,

Answer (score 1):

Go to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/TAG, where TAG is your tag that you want to follow. Go to the bottom of the page and you'll see a link with this title: **highest voted TAG questions feed**

Comment: How is it what the OP wants?

Comment: I don't see a "highest voted TAG questions feed" near the bottom of the page (any longer?). Or am I blind?