# email me when someone tags a question with one of my interesting tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-watching, email

Kinda like [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-interesting-tags), I'd like to see a feature where I get a periodic email (daily for instance) with any new questions with tags from my Interesting Tags group.

This should be selectable at the tag level because we'd all drown in noise if we got emailled about every question tagged "JonSkeet" but for those lower-throughput tags we're interested in it can be easy not to notice the question on the homepage and annoying to be always clicking through the tags looking for anything interesting.

**Update 1**

We have the ability to be updated on questions we ask and answer so theoretically this is an extension of that concept, with the addition of the ability to specify it per tag.

**Update 2**

Using existing RSS capabilities has been suggested (@Randell).  Of course this provides you with the basic information but some things we can do with an email are:

1. have it find you wherever you happened to be logged in (for those of us using webmail)
2. receive notifications only about new questions
3. have a single email summarise activity across numerous tags (lots of tags showing up in my RSS reader right now)

Yes, yes I know if you're using a web-based RSS reader that it too will follow you wherever you're logged in but I (at least) tend to be more interested in my email.

**Update 3**

So there seems to be some RSS love going here.  Fair enough - RSS is a useful tool and I have gone about adding things to my RSS reader, but I still think that an email waiting in my inbox each morning with a brief summary (digest as @Cometbill puts it) of the new stuff would be a useful feature.  **I do emphasise this would be best suited to low-throughput tags.  Also any real-time or high frequency feature would probably produce enough email to warp the fabric of space time but 1 per day per user wouldn't**.  Tags like C# or Java would probably not be suitable.

Comment: +1 was looking for the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try a rrs2email service like [xFruits](http://www.xfruits.com/) or [rss2pdf](http://rss2pdf.com/). They let you aggregate different feeds into one too before mailing.

Comment: +2 if I could - they look pretty cool

Comment: accepted as providing the closest thing to what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the tag feeds accessible through `http://<SO Trilogy site>/questions/tagged/<tag>.`

Comment: indeed I did see a note like that in the RSS question I linked to.  But I feel there may still be times when a user would prefer an email (individual preferences methinks).

Comment: +1 though for suggesting an existing solution

Answer (score 1):

Potentially that's vast amounts of email SO will have to send out, and it's going to be a problem for someone who (quite reasonably) tags C# or Java or similar high level tags.

This is exactly the kind of problem RSS was designed to solve, i.e. I think we already have the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

A daily digest of those tags might be interesting, with the question header, and a count of how many replies were recewived.

Not quite as interactive as JRE wanted, but possibly useful.

I know I'd like to see questions on SOME of that tags I marked as interesting. Only some though.

Comment: I did mention that I'd be happy with something like a daily.  In fact a separate email for each question would probably defeat the purpose of such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

[Tag sets on Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/) now support **emailing you as new questions arrive in your tag set.**

To set it up:

- visit the [tag sets page](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/popular) at stackexchange.com
- browse someone else's tag set *or* establish your own tag set
- look in the right hand sidebar for the envelope to enable email options

[image]

Remember that Tag Sets work across *all* Stack Exchange websites -- so you are not limited to a single site.