# How to get email notification on posts I didn't create?

Tags: support, email, email-notification

There are some posts that seem interesting, and I want to get an email notification when answers are posted, even though I'm not the one who asked the question. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Each <s>tag</s> question has an Atom feed. You could use [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com) to consume the feed and subscribe to the Feedburner feed via e-mail.

Comment: For *tags*, the global tag sets [support emailing out of the box](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17588/email-me-when-someone-tags-a-question-with-one-of-my-interesting-tags/72452#72452), without the need to use the feeds. But: each *question* has such feed too, so this still works.

Comment: @Arjan: Nuts! I forgot about tag sets. You should make that an answer and I'll delete this one.

Comment: No, @Al, the question is about questions, not tags. So your answer is correct, when you replace *tag* with *question*!

Comment: Ah. The original question said "topics" which I took to mean "tags". It's since been edited, and thus my original answer makes *no* sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RSS Feed for this. 
You can take `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds` for last 30 questions

Comment: @ykartal : Yeaa, but I don't like RSS Feeds. Don't we have email notifications?

Comment: On user profile page at the "Prefs" TAB only      
 "I'd like email notifications of activity on questions I've asked" 
 "I don't want notifications of activity on questions I've favorited" options available

Comment: @ykartal : Thanks, and I want to get notification from my desired topics which I don't created. How can we do this?

Comment: Hımmm, I understand if second option not checked and you have favorited questions, you would take notifications from site.  For Favorited the question you can see a star under the question's score.

Comment: In addition, I think stackoverflow.com sends daily e-mail notifictaions to users not mail them at the same time(instantly on post sent)