# How to Get an RSS Feed of Latest Questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, questions, feed

How can I get an RSS feed (for my iGoogle page) of all the latest stackoverflow questions, filterd by my tags?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-interesting-tags

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
/feeds/tag/tag1+or+tag2+or+tag3
```

E.g.:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/jquery+or+mvc

Comment: can i get a feed of the questions _i've_ asked?

Comment: @Michael Yes, the URL would be like: http://{stack exchange site}/feeds/question/{question id}