# you.stackexchange.com - an easy way to manage your sites and favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, site-crossover

I spend a lot of time bouncing around from one site to another to another as I'm interested in the topics they have to offer. As stack exchange continues to grow, and as I continue to find more and more sites that interest me. Because I don't always have the time to go to each site to see what interesting things are on them all, I typically will go to my top 3 sites, and then one or two other sites each day.

I propose a portal, something like `you.stackexchange.com` or `my.stackexchange.com` where you could add tags and have it crawl the other sites to generate the questions you're most likely to be interested in. It also could use some clustering algorithms to determine questions you're likely to enjoy based on their tags and the tags to other questions you've viewed, voted, answered, or otherwise interacted with.

I know this is similar to the [RSS feed of your favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags) question, but I think it is significantly different and of a bigger scope. The bottom line is StackExchange needs to be able to scale with the amount of time users have available to it.

I'm also open to suggestions and alternatives (and constructive criticism!) to this idea.

Comment: How would this be different from [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can already do this using **my filters** on [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com).

For example, the following screenshot shows how you might go about creating a filter for C# game development. Note that you can create a filter across *all* Stack Exchange sites.

[image: Screenshot of a C# game development filter]

Comment: How have I only just found out about this!!?!?!?!

Comment: @Matt Probably because, apart from the [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838), this isn't really promoted on the Stack Exchange sites. I didn't discover this until I started spending time on Meta, either!

Comment: Wow. This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Your image didn't really make sense at first due to a lack of [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775), but I got it eventually. Thanks!

Comment: @glowcoder Now with freehand circles!