# "Favorite Tags" RSS feed should not list things that also have "Ignored Tags"

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, feed

When displaying the questions on a site, questions with a Favorite tag are highlighted, while questions with an Ignored tag are grayed out.  Questions with *both* a Favorite and Ignored tag are grayed out, which I think is good.  Ignored overrides Favorite.  I can Favorite "audio" on Stack Overflow, but then Ignore "iphone audio" or "jquery audio", which I have no interest in.

We now have a ["Favorite Tags" feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags/101276#101276), which is great, but it doesn't pay attention to the "Ignored Tags".  I think Ignored tags should override Favorites tags here, too, and not show up in the feed.  It should behave the same way as the site.

If there's a legitimate reason for Favorite to override Ignored, then both options should be available.

Comment: But what if I want the favourite tags feed to override the ignored tags feed? It's an equally valid requirement

Comment: @ChrisF: Why would you want that?  That's not how the Ignored tags work on the site.  If there's a legitimate reason for that behavior, then both should be possible.

Comment: If a question is tagged with one of my interesting tags then, by definition, I'm interested in seeing it. Whether that overrides the fact I'm ignoring another tag is surely my preference.

Comment: @ChrisF: Then why prevent people from seeing it the other way if that's their preference?

Comment: You can still see them - just don't tick the "remove ignored flags" option ;)

Comment: @ChrisF: I don't see that option.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: The point here is that the behaviour between the RSS feed and the site itself is inconsistent.

Comment: Go to your profile page and on the "prefs" tab there's the option "hide ignored tags" under the list of ignored tags. Do you have that ticked? If you clear it you'll see questions with your ignored tags but they'll be de-emphasised.

Comment: @ChrisF: This request is about the RSS feed, not the site's listing: http://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags  The RSS feed shows all questions with Favorite tags, even if they also have Ignored tags.

Comment: Sorry - I thought you were comparing the behaviour of the feed to the site. I'll shut up now.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible through the [filter creation interface at stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/filters).

However, you can manually create a feed url and prefix with the minus sign the tags that you do not want to see. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python+-django will give you all question tagged python but not django.

Found this information on the [stackoverflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/).

You could gather your current list of favorite and ignored tags by extending the script that I mentioned in [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/29866/138613).