# Filtered question feed

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RSS feed of your favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags)

I have a number of favourite tags on Stack Overflow. I would like a single page or feed that shows me questions with these tags only.

Is this currently possible?

Comment: Yep, that's possible. See the top answer to the other question.