# When I click "Next" it shows next page but with same questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, pagination

[image]

When I click "Next" it shows next page but some questions are same with previous page's questions. For Example in previous page I see some question then I click next and see same question again.

Comment: Works the same for me when browsing high-activity tags. Some questions indeed reappear when I go to next page. You're likely take some time to read through first page. As a result, when you click on Next page, newer questions push some of questions to second page.

Comment: I think Stack Overflow engineers can find solution to this problem.

Comment: There isn't really a "problem"; At the time you click to view Page 2, what you see *is* the correct information for page 2. You are looking at a time-sorted list; you should *not expect anything different*, because anything different would be incorrect.

Comment: Andrew Barber what is the our purpose when we click to next? I want to see only other questions. I dont want to see same questions again.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a *static* website. Its data changes *constantly*. If you hit `refresh` on Page 1, you will also notice that the content there *changes*... new posts were made in the interim, therefore pushing other posts that were on Page 1 back to Page 2. That's exactly what you should expect from a *dynamic* website. If you want to see more items in a row in a static view, click to view more items per page; see the items on the bottom-right: `15 30 50 per page`... click on the `50`.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas @AndrewBarber but I am not agree with you. Page numbers is not important I want to see only new questions. I expect only this function from "next button". There must be solution for such problems in dynamic content sites.

Comment: @Andrew He wants to see "new questions" in the sense of questions he hasn't seen already (i.e. those pushed back from page 1)

Comment: @slhck I would like the internets to remember all the websites I have visited and for google not to show me stuff I've already seen in a given search.  That doesn't mean it's likely to happen or that it's a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a bug - the system is doing exactly what you ask, which is giving you questions 16-30 in **the current list**. "The current list" is a different list pretty much every time you ask for it, of course, but that doesn't change what you asked for.

What you *may* be interested in is the answer to this question: [RSS feed of your favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags). If you want to see new questions **but only ever see a question once**, the RSS 'news' model seems more appropriate than paginated a constantly-changing list.

See if it does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Per screen shot it looks like you use default setting to display 15 questions per page. Per my recollection, "reappearing questions" were indeed a noticeable annoyance with this setting.

To me, the annoyance has gone when I changed settings to display 50 questions per page:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8whn.jpg]

Not that above change magically fixed Next page - quite opposite, there are typically more of reappearing questions shown at 50-per-page setting. But somehow, difficult to tell why, just somehow this doesn't feel wrong anymore.

Maybe this is because with 50-per-page setting I spend much more time browsing first page questions so that seeing "reappearing questions" after I click Next feels justified.

---

> Page numbers is not important I want to see only new questions. I expect only this function from "next button". There must be solution for such problems in dynamic content sites.

Sure there is a solution. For the case of SO though I doubt that it is worth implementing. Thing is what you want involves certain complication of UI. Just think of it...

1. imagine user opening first page and keeping it hanging *for a few hours*
2. imagine *hundred or something of new questions* appearing while first page hangs
3. now, what would user expect when they click second page after above?

Would you expect just showing a second page as it would have been few hours ago? Would that feel right taking into account that as of now, this would be 22nd page not 2nd (remember *hundred or something of new questions appearing while first page hangs*)?

- That would definitely feel **wrong** to me (and I guess not to me alone). To handle that, one would have to establish sort of update notification [like one that is currently shown for new answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBNpJ.jpg). Is it worth to implement such a solution? not to me - as I already mentioned, things just feel good enough to me after I switched to 50-per-page view.

Comment: ı have voted up because good suggestion I hasn't noticed it. But this is not actual solution.

Comment: @faridmovsumov well your problem isn't an actual problem so "not actual solution" seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Question lists are cached for two minutes for all users - it's not really feasible for us to store which questions each user has seen during their session.

The other answers give good work-arounds for this intended behavior.