# RSS feed for multiple tags fails

Tags: bug, status-norepro, feed, tag-search

I tried to create a RSS feed for multiple tags, sort of working on creating a feed that would give me similar features as the [favorite tags rss](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags), but more flexible.

So I created the following tag search: [C#+regex or .net+regex or linq* or tfs* or fxcop* or azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%23%2Bregex%20or%20.net%2Bregex%20or%20linq*%20or%20tfs*%20or%20fxcop*%20or%20azure). Which works great to retrieve just what I'm after and would allow me to split up the tag search to different feeds if I wanted...

The page even shows a RSS subscribe icon in Chrome, but when clicking it it doesn't bring up any items. It seems either my tag+tag or the tag* option is breaking the RSS subscription, while the page loads just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with crafting RSS strings manually. For example, [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) and [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) for Server Fault:

`http://serverfault.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=windows+or+ssh&sort=newest`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce this issue in the current build of our sites. If the problem remains, please let me know! PS - due to tag limits implemented for performance reasons, the original tag search in your post has 0 results.

Comment: I would rather see *too many tags specified* than *0 results* in this case.