# What are the limitations on adding multi-tag chat feeds?

Tags: support, chat, feed

Thanks to [this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4176/make-rss-feeds-capable-of-using-multi-tags) and the ability to use the OR operator, we can have multiple tags and can include wildcards in tags to make broad filters in RSS feeds.  In the main Sci-fi & Fantasy.SE [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/mos-eisley?tab=feeds) we use this to get a kinda ridiculous filtered feed of questions on Movies & TV.SE that are sci-fi/fantasy.

I was trying to expand it just now to add a few more works.  Starting with `star-trek*` is the new stuff in the feed URL:

```
http://movies.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?sort=newest&tagnames=science-fiction+or+fantasy+or+star-wars+or+game-of-thrones+or+interstellar+or+batman+or+lord-of-the-rings+or+marvel-cinematic-universe+or+doctor-who+or+star-trek*+or+the-hobbit+or+harry-potter+or+the-matrix+or+despicable-me
```

Trying to save this monstrosity of a feed URL generates a cute cat developer error page.  What are the limitations of the chat feeds that I'm bumping into here?

Comment: Just came across [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242185/369802) and your post while digging for some info on RSS Feed stuff, and I think you're hitting the limitation on number of tags described in the answer there. I don't know the exact number of the limit, though you have more tags here than the example there.