# What are the RSS capabilities of SE and SE chat rooms?

Tags: feature-request, chat, android-app-feed

Are there any ways to get an Android RSS feed specifically for chat?

Related question: [RSS feed of your favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags?rq=1)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by 'RSS capabilities of chat'? Do you want a feed of all messages? Do you want new entries to a feed to be posted in a chatroom? (you can do that) Do you want a feed of all new chatrooms created? I'm not exactly sure what you want.

Comment: Any feed in general, it doesn't have to be special. I was simply asking if it existed. Although if it doesn't exist, I would think anything would suffice.

Comment: Well, there aren't any RSS feeds for new chat messages (which is a good thing, since some rooms get over a thousand messages per day, so your reader would fill up *very* fast). There are however websockets which you can use if you want to develop something related to chat.