# RSS feeds for a set of tags (with OR clause) are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

I used to receive [RSS feed on a set of tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/is-there-a-way-to-do-rss-feeds-on-a-set-of-tags), such as https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java+or+spring&sort=newest, but today it started to produce 404, though feed link at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+spring still points to that address.

Feeds on individual tags ( https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java&sort=newest) and on intersection of tags ( https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java+spring&sort=newest) are working correctly.

Comment: OK, we're investigating. We have some recent code (i.e. deployed today) in that area that is likely related.

Comment: should all be golden now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found and fixed; deploying momentarily